# Is it possible to dispatch no more than N number of messages from the queue at a given time with distributed consumers?

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, producer-consumer, pika

I have a distributed system that reads messages from RabbitMQ. In my situation now I need to process no more than N msgs/s.

For example: Imagine service `A` that sends text messages (SMS). This service can only handle 100 msgs/s. My system has multiple consumers that reads data from RabbitMQ. Each message needs to be  processed first and than be send to service `A`. Processing time is always different.

So the question:

- Is it possible to configure queue to dispatch no more than 100 msgs/s to multiple consumers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `prefetch_size` parameter of the [qos](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html#basic.qos) method to limit throughput to your consumers.

```
channel.basic_qos(100);
```

See also: http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/05/11/some-queuing-theory-throughput-latency-and-bandwidth/

Comment: This is very nice article. But I have one question, Imagine situation, where my consumers are on different servers, and don't communicate with each other. Each consumer uses `basic.get()` (that returns only one msg from queue). Will `prefetch_size` work with `basic.get()`?

Comment: I have never used `basic.get`, but I think it will not work, because you are just picking one message from the queue at a time with basic.get and poll for the next one. Why don't you use `basic.consume` in your workers? `consume` will also be more performant and better scalable from what I read.